# Reaching end of list in prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I've been given the question:

> Define a predicate ordered/1, which checks if a list of integers is correctly in ascending order. For example, the goal `ordered([1,3,7,11])` should succeed, as should the goal `ordered([1,3,3,7])`, whereas the goal `ordered([1,7,3,9])` should fail.

So far I have this:

```
ordered([]).    
ordered([N, M|Ns]):-
    append(M, Ns, Tail),
    ordered(Tail),
    N =< M.
```

But it fails on every list.

I have deduced that the reason it fails is because it reaches the end number in the list then tries to compare that number against an empty list. Obviously this fails because you can't compare an integer to an empty list. Even if you could and it, say, returned `0` for an empty list, it would still return false as the number would be greater than `0`, not less than.

I can't find a solution... Any ideas? Thanks, Jon.

---

#### Edit

So, some slightly amended code:

```
ordered([]).
ordered([N]):-
    N >= 0.
ordered([N, M|Ns]):-
    append(M, Ns, Tail),
    ordered(Tail),
    N =< M.
```

This now works for `ordered([1])`, but bigger lists still don't run correctly.

Should I include something like `ordered([N, M|Ns])` in the definition?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well that, in the end, was rediculously easy to fix.

Here is the correct code.

```
ordered([]).

ordered([N, M|Ns]):-
 append([M], Ns, Tail),
 ordered(Tail),
 N =< M.

ordered([M]).
```

ordered([M]). deals with the single-element list as described above.

The real root of my problem was not including [] around the M in the append function.

Whats the ettiquette regarding awarding the correct answer? You've both helped muchly.

Jon

Comment: I think we both missed the point that you were also using append incorrectly, and focused on the single-element case. Not sure what the etiquette is - I'd pick the answer that is more formally correct wrt. the original question.

Comment: Since you didn't get any answers that ultimately solved the problem, accepting your own answer makes the most sense.

Comment: Also note that `append([M], Ns, Tail)` is the same as `Tail = [M| Ns]`.

Comment: `?- ordered([2,1|_]).    loops, unexpected.`

Answer (score 5):

(assuming this is homework, I hesitate to give a complete solution).

Looking at your code, try to find out how it would unify `?- ordered([1]).`
Run this query mentally (or using trace/0) and see what it does, step by step, and how it computes its result.

Also, please try to get "returns a value" out of your mind when thinking prolog. Prolog predicates don't return anything.

Comment: Not homework, but a past exam question. We have to define actual predicates in our exam. It's a bit rubbish as you have no way to test our solutions in the exam. Probably would get *some* marks for the above. While i'm practicing, however, I'm sat at the computer testing all my solutions and this one failed! :( Thanks for your help. I'll have another go at it.

Comment: Ok. When mentally tracing through a prolog predicate, take explicit note of how variables get bound/unified.

Comment: So running through my code for ordered([3]): N is 3, while M is [] or null. And the appending M to Ns (where Ns is []) results in Tail being []. So i either need to check for when M is [] or null. Can things be 'null' or are they always an empty list, [] ?

Comment: Right, well having worked out how to use trace, I've now realised my original code was wrong. I was missing a [] around the M when appending the list.

Comment: Actually, no. A single-element list just doesn't unify with [N, M|Ns] - so it's not that M is null (what value would Ns then have?). null and the empty list are really the same (actually, I think there is no proper "null").

Answer (score 2):

I think your solution is not also tail-recursion-friendly.
Think something like that would do:

```
ordered([]) :-!.
ordered([_]):-!.
ordered([A,B|T]) :-
    A =< B,
    !,
    ordered([B|T]).
```

Answer (score 2):

If your Prolog system supports [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd), check if it offers the library predicate [`clpfd:chain/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html).

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

If so, simply write:

```
?- chain([1,3,7,11],#<).
true.

?- chain([1,3,3,7],#=<).
true.
?- chain([1,3,3,7],#<).
false.

?- chain([1,7,3,9],#<).
false.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [SICStus Prolog](https://sicstus.sics.se/),
[my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30997217/4609915) will not work, as the 
[clpfd library in SICStus Prolog](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dclpfd.html)
 does not offer the library predicate 
[`chain/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=chain/2) included with 
[SWI-Prolog's clpfd library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd).

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- assert(clpfd:full_answer).
```

Don't panic! Simply implement predicate `ordered/1` like this:

```
ordered([]).
ordered([X|Xs]) :- 
   ordered_prev(Xs,X).

ordered_prev([]     ,_ ).
ordered_prev([X1|Xs],X0) :- 
   X0 #=< X1,
   ordered_prev(Xs,X1).
```

Let's see it in action with SICStus Prolog 4.3.2.
Here's the most general query:

```
?- ordered(Xs).
  Xs = []
; Xs = [_A]
; Xs = [_A,_B],    _A#=<_B,          _A in inf..sup, _B in inf..sup
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C], _A#=<_B, _B#=<_C, _A in inf..sup, _B in inf..sup, _C in inf..sup
... % an infinity of solutions follows: omitted for the sake of brevity.
```

And here are the queries the OP suggested:

```
?- ordered([1,3,7,11]).
yes                                  % succeeds deterministically
?- ordered([1,3,3,7]).
yes                                  % succeeds deterministically
?- ordered([1,7,3,9]).
no
```

Note that both succeeding queries in above example did not leave any useless choicepoints behind, thanks to first argument indexing.

Answer (score 1):

You're quite right: according to your code there are only two possible ways a list can be `ordered`:

1. It's empty
2. The first two items are in the correct order, and the rest of the list is `ordered`

Those are certainly both correct statements, but what about the list `[3]`?  Isn't that `ordered` too? Obviously a list with only one element is ordered, yet you have no provision for expressing that: it fits neither your base case nor your recursive case.

The single-element list is another case hiding here that you haven't addressed yet.  Since this is independent of the two rules you've already defined, you might want to consider a way to address this special case separately.

Answer (score 1):

To efficiently use first-argument indexing:

```
ordered([]).
ordered([H|T]) :-
    ordered_(T, H).

ordered_([], _).
ordered_([H|T], P) :-
    P @=< H,
    ordered_(T, H).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- ordered([1,2,3,4,5]).
true.

?- ordered([a,b,c,d,g]).
true.

?- ordered([b,c,a,d]).
false.
```

This does not leave an unwanted choicepoint, uses [standard order](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=standardorder) (so works with not just integers), and is fast. Performance comparison:

JonB:

```
?- garbage_collect, numlist(1, 1_000_000, L), time(ordered(L)).
% 3,999,996 inferences, 0.872 CPU in 0.873 seconds (100% CPU, 4589226 Lips)
```

vs this:

```
?- garbage_collect, numlist(1, 1_000_000, L), time(ordered(L)).
% 2,000,001 inferences, 0.046 CPU in 0.046 seconds (100% CPU, 43662698 Lips)
```

Comment: "Using swi-prolog's features, this can be even faster:" But your code only uses standard features...

Comment: `@=<` doesn't seem to be widely supported in Prolog implementations, or ISO-standard. Or isn't a search-engine-friendly combination of characters :-)

Comment: It's an ISO Prolog Core standard operator for term comparison. See e.g. http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec78 (which clearly marks ISO features).

Comment: *Standard order*, as you call it, is in SWI different to ISO term order (7.2). For one, ISO uses the type first, and thus all floats are smaller than all integers, whereas in SWI it depends on the particular rounding mode you employ. There are many other differences.

Comment: Also note, that this question was about ordered numbers and not terms.

Comment: `?- ordered([X,1]),X=2.
   X = 2, unexpected.`

Answer (score 1):

Having much better performance than my previous answer involving `freeze`:

```
ascending_or_equal_freeze(L) :-
    freeze(L, ascending_or_equal_freeze_start1_(L)).

ascending_or_equal_freeze_start1_([]).
ascending_or_equal_freeze_start1_([H|T]) :-
    ascending_or_equal_freeze_start2_(T, H).

ascending_or_equal_freeze_start2_([], _).
ascending_or_equal_freeze_start2_([H|T], P) :-
    % Need 2 elements, to start comparison
    ascending_or_equal_freeze_([P,H|T], []).

ascending_or_equal_freeze_([], _).
ascending_or_equal_freeze_([H|T], Before) :-
    ascending_or_equal_freeze_search_(Before, <,  H),
    ascending_or_equal_freeze_search_(T, >,  H),
    (   ground(H) ->
        % Can cut the list short, H is completely comparable
        Before1 = [H]
    ;   Before1 = [H|Before]
    ),
    freeze(T, ascending_or_equal_freeze_(T, Before1)).

ascending_or_equal_freeze_search_(L, Comp, P) :-
    ascending_or_equal_freeze_search_loop_(L, Comp, P, [], L).

ascending_or_equal_freeze_search_loop_(L, Comp, P, Visited, OrigL) :-
    (   \+ \+ L = []
    % End of list - resume search when P is instantiated further
    ->  ascending_or_equal_freeze_when_(OrigL, Comp, P)
    ;   L = [H|T],
        (   ?=(H, P)
        % Can compare with certainty
        ->  compare_or_equal(Comp, H, P, ActualComp),
            (   ActualComp = (=)
            % Elements in-between must be same
            ->  maplist(=(P), Visited)
            ;   true
            )
        ;   ascending_or_equal_freeze_search_loop_(T, Comp, P, [H|Visited], OrigL)
        )
    ).

ascending_or_equal_freeze_when_(L, Comp, P) :-
    (   \+ \+ L = []
    % Nothing to compare
    ->  true
    ;   term_variables(P, Vars),
        (   Vars == []
        % P is ground
        ->  true
        % Resume search when instantiated further
        ;   when_nonvar_any(Vars, ascending_or_equal_freeze_search_(L, Comp, P))
        )
    ).

compare_or_equal(Comp, X, Y, ActualComp) :-
    compare(C, X, Y),
    compare_or_equal_(C, Comp, ActualComp).

compare_or_equal_(=, _, =).
compare_or_equal_(<, <, <).
compare_or_equal_(>, >, >).

when_nonvar_any([], _).
when_nonvar_any([H|T], Action) :-
    nonvar_elem_cond([H|T], Cond),
    when(Cond, Action). 
    
nonvar_elem_cond([H|T], L) :-
    nonvar_elem_cond_(T, H, L).
    
nonvar_elem_cond_([], H, nonvar(H)).
nonvar_elem_cond_([H|T], P, nonvar(P);L) :-
    nonvar_elem_cond_(T, H, L).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- ascending_or_equal_freeze(L), L = [1,2,X,Y,5,6|T].
L = [1, 2, X, Y, 5, 6|T],
when(nonvar(X), ascending_or_equal_freeze_search_([2], <, X)),
when(nonvar(X), ascending_or_equal_freeze_search_([Y, 5, 6|T], >, X)),
when(nonvar(Y), ascending_or_equal_freeze_search_([X, 2], <, Y)),
when(nonvar(Y), ascending_or_equal_freeze_search_([5, 6|T], >, Y)),
freeze(T, ascending_or_equal_freeze_(T, [6])).

?- numlist(1, 4000, L), time(ascending_or_equal_freeze(L)).
% 64,000 inferences, 0.004 CPU in 0.004 seconds (98% CPU, 15798229 Lips)

% Automatically joins up logically-equal segments
?- L = [_, b, _, _, _, _, X, _], ascending_or_equal_freeze(L), X = b.
L = [_A, b, b, b, b, b, b, _B],
X = b,
when(nonvar(_A), ascending_or_equal_freeze_search_([b, b, b, b, b, b, _B], >, _A)),
when(nonvar(_B), ascending_or_equal_freeze_search_([b, b, b, b, b, b], <, _B)).
```

Comment: Ascending or equal ≈ increasing

Comment: This is **way** too complex to understand. Just keep in mind that 8 lines suffice. It most certainly has the same error than your original failed attempt since you use `?=`.  And the `\+ \+ L = []` looks suspicious too.

Comment: What's suspicious about `\+ \+ L = []`? Seems a convenient way to determine the end of an open or closed list, being `freeze`-compatible, and keeping an open list open.

Comment: I cannot see what the meaning of this is. Either you opt for [] or you don't...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `append/3`.

**edit1** to satisfy @false.  In order to make it tail recursive friendly it has to eliminate backtracking.  This is tail-recursive and only slight variation on @Xonix:

```
ordered([X|[]]):-!.

ordered([X,Y|Ys]) :- 
    X =< Y,
    !,
    ordered([Y|Ys]).
```

**edit2** Take it a step further to eliminate lists that have less than two elements

```
ordered([X,Y|[]]):- X =< Y,!.

ordered([X,Y|Ys]) :- 
    X =< Y,
    !,
    ordered([Y|Ys]).
```

Comment: This uses space proportional to the length of the list - and that space is not freed automatically!

Comment: @false.  Would changing the clause order help the space issue?

Comment: "edit2" is weird. I would always use a variant of `ordered/1` that handles **all cases** (including the ones that do not involve comparisons: `[]` and `[_]`) and (if required) **exclude** those cases **later** by using `ordered/1` like so: `?- Xs = [_,_|_], ordered(Xs).`

Comment: `ordered([1,2|_])` succeeds deterministically - suggesting that this is fine. Generally speaking,  cuts are a clear sign that something is cut away - quite frequently it is good semantics that is cut away.

Comment: @repeat the point of my post is really that you shouldn't use `append/3` because then it is not optimized for tail recursion.

Answer (score 0):

A short but slow version:

```
increasing_freeze_slow(L) :-
    freeze(L, increasing_freeze_slow_(L, [])).

increasing_freeze_slow_([], _).
increasing_freeze_slow_([H|T], Ps) :-
    % Apply when_ground_gte to the previous list elements
    maplist(when_ground_gte(H), Ps),
    freeze(T, increasing_freeze_slow_(T, [H|Ps])).

% When comparable, is greater than or equal
when_ground_gte(High, Low) :-
    when((ground(High), ground(Low)), High @>= Low).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- increasing_freeze_slow(L), length(L, 4).
L = [_A, _B, _C, _D],
when((ground(_B), ground(_A)), _B@>=_A),
when((ground(_C), ground(_B)), _C@>=_B),
when((ground(_C), ground(_A)), _C@>=_A),
when((ground(_D), ground(_C)), _D@>=_C),
when((ground(_D), ground(_B)), _D@>=_B),
when((ground(_D), ground(_A)), _D@>=_A).
```

It will compare all the list elements to all of the other list elements, as soon as they are comparable with certainty.

This comes with a performance penalty, but allows e.g.:

```
?- increasing_freeze_slow(L), L = [1,X,3], X = 2.
L = [1, 2, 3],
X = 2.

?- increasing_freeze_slow(L), L = [1,X,3], X = 99.
false.
```

Comment: `?- when_gte(X-1,1-2).
false.` but `?- X = 2, when_gte(X-1,1-2).
X = 2.`

Comment: Fixed using `ground`. A better comparison method, though, is at https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/how-to-compare-3-without-surprises-on-non-ground-terms/6386/14

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *better comparison method*. Using `when((nonvar(X),nonvar(Y)), _)` is malaprop in any case.