# Prolog: Arrangements of k elements with sum of elements S

Tags: list, prolog, combinations, permutation, clpfd

I am trying to compute arrangements of `K` elements in Prolog, where the sum of their elements is equal to a given `S`. So, I know that arrangements can be computed by finding the combinations and then permute them. I know how to compute combinations of `K` elements, something like:

```
comb([E|_], 1, [E]).
comb([_|T], K, R) :-
   comb(T, K, R).
comb([H|T], K, [H|R]) :-
   K > 1,
   K1 is K-1,
   comb(T, K1, R).
```

The permutations of a list, having the property that the sum of their elements is equal to a given S, I know to compute like this:

```
insert(E, L, [E|L]).
insert(E, [H|T], [H|R]) :-
   insert(E, T, R).

perm([], []).
perm([H|T], P) :-
   perm(T, R),
   insert(H, R, P).

sumList([], 0).
sumList([H], H) :-
   number(H).
sumList([H|Tail], R1) :-
   sumList(Tail, R),
   R1 is R+H.

perms(L, S, R) :-
   perm(L, R),
   sumList(R, S1),
   S = S1.

allPerms(L, LP) :-
   findall(R, perms(L,R), LP).
```

The problem is that I do not know how to combine them, in order to get the arrangements of `K` elements, having the sum of elements equal to a given `S`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you working with *any* numbers, or rather with integers only?

Comment: Which Prolog processor are you using? SICStus? SWI?

Answer (score 5):

Use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Using SWI-Prolog 7.3.16 we query:

```
?- length(Zs,4), Zs ins 1..4, sum(Zs,#=,7), labeling([],Zs).
   Zs = [1,1,1,4]
;  Zs = [1,1,2,3]
;  Zs = [1,1,3,2]
;  Zs = [1,1,4,1]
;  Zs = [1,2,1,3]
;  Zs = [1,2,2,2]
;  Zs = [1,2,3,1]
;  Zs = [1,3,1,2]
;  Zs = [1,3,2,1]
;  Zs = [1,4,1,1]
;  Zs = [2,1,1,3]
;  Zs = [2,1,2,2]
;  Zs = [2,1,3,1]
;  Zs = [2,2,1,2]
;  Zs = [2,2,2,1]
;  Zs = [2,3,1,1]
;  Zs = [3,1,1,2]
;  Zs = [3,1,2,1]
;  Zs = [3,2,1,1]
;  Zs = [4,1,1,1].
```

To eliminate "redundant modulo permutation" solutions use [`chain/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=chain/2):

```
?- length(Zs,4), Zs ins 1..4, chain(Zs,#=<), sum(Zs,#=,7), labeling([],Zs).
   Zs = [1,1,1,4]
;  Zs = [1,1,2,3]
;  Zs = [1,2,2,2]
;  false.
```

Comment: I try to do this qst but I have this result (length=3,Sum3) :`List = [_A,_B,_C],
_A in inf..sup,
_B in inf..sup,
_C in inf..sup ?` how I can recover values from `inf..sup`

Comment: @AnsPiter try supplying a value instead of a variable in `Sum3`? To paraphrase your code, you're basically saying, "give me three things that add up to anything." CLP came back with, "here's three things that have any value." This is why repeat gave `Zs ins 1..4` and `sum(Zs, #=, 7)` to constrain the solution space.

Comment: @AnsPiter. Daniel is right. If you use SICStus, do `assert(clpfd:full_answer)` to ensure the [tag:prolog-toplevel] shows residual constraints—so you don't get the impression the proof is complete when it is not!

Comment: @repeat,@Daniel Lyons,  thnks

Answer (score 4):

I use SWI-Prolog.
You can write that

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

arrangement(K, S, L) :-
    % we have a list of K numbers
    length(L, K),
    % these numbers are between 1 (or 0) and S
    maplist(between(1, S), L),
    % the sum of these numbers is S
    foldl(\X^Y^Z^(Z is X+Y), L, 0, S).
```

The result

```
 ?- arrangement(5, 10, L).
L = [1, 1, 1, 1, 6] ;
L = [1, 1, 1, 2, 5] ;
L = [1, 1, 1, 3, 4] ;
L = [1, 1, 1, 4, 3] .
```

You can use also a CLP(FD) library.

Edited after the remark of **@repeat**.

Comment: What is that `when(ground(L), ...)` for? Which use cases can profit from this?

Comment: @repeat You're absolute right, there is no need of that.

Answer (score 1):

This response is similar to response of **@repeat**

predicates that below are implemented using the **SICStus 4.3.2** tool

after simple modification of `gen_list(+,+,?)`

edit **Code**

```
gen_list(Length,Sum,List) :-    length(List,Length), 
                                domain(List,0,Sum), 
                                sum(List,#=,Sum), 
                                labeling([],List),

                                % to avoid duplicate results
                                ordered(List).
```

**Test**

```
| ?- gen_list(4,7,L).
L = [0,0,0,7] ? ;
L = [0,0,1,6] ? ;
L = [0,0,2,5] ? ;
L = [0,0,3,4] ? ;
L = [0,1,1,5] ? ;
L = [0,1,2,4] ? ;
L = [0,1,3,3] ? ;
L = [0,2,2,3] ? ;
L = [1,1,1,4] ? ;
L = [1,1,2,3] ? ;
L = [1,2,2,2] ? ;
no
```

Comment: Keep it simple! With SICStus Prolog 4.3.2, put the library predicates `domain/3` and `sum/3` to good use: `?- length(Zs,4), domain(Zs,1,4), sum(Zs,#=,7), labeling([],Zs).`

Comment: @repeat thnx ,but  how  I can filter the duplicate result like [0,0,0,7] and [0,7,0,0]...?

Comment: @repeat  maybe no way to avoid duplicate results

Comment: I did not get that. What do you mean with "maybe no way to avoid duplicate results"? Have you tried `ordered/1` (link above)?

Comment: OK! But why do you write `labeling([],List), ordered(List), Res = List ; false`  and not `ordered(List), labeling([],List)` and use `List` throughout? In general, posting constraints before labeling is preferable.

Comment: @repeat it's ok now ?

Comment: Better, yes. But why put the `labeling/2` goal before the `ordered/1` goal? Here's some good material that explains why doing labeling last is right: https://github.com/triska/clpfd/blob/master/clpfd.pdf

Comment: @repeat I try to put the  ordered/1 before the labeling/2 but the result is not filtering

Comment: Don't just pick any implementation! Stick to the one presented in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31094645/4609915 .

Comment: @repeat Triska's article is very interesting also CLP(B)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that permutations could be relevant for your problem. Since the sum operation is commutative, the order of elements should be actually irrelevant. So, after this correction

```
sumList([], 0).
%sumList([H], H) :-
%   number(H).
sumList([H|Tail], R1) :-
   sumList(Tail, R),
   R1 is R+H.
```

you can just use your predicates

```
'arrangements of K elements'(Elements, K, Sum, Arrangement) :-
    comb(Elements, K, Arrangement),
    sumList(Arrangement, Sum).
```

test:

```
'arrangements of K elements'([1,2,3,4,5,6],3,11,A).
A = [2, 4, 5] ;
A = [2, 3, 6] ;
A = [1, 4, 6] ;
false.
```

You already know how to use findall/3 to get all lists at once, if you need them.